# Detect image content change with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am using HTML file on a local PC for image viewing.
The HTML is very simple:

```
<html>
<body scroll="no">

<img border="0" src="DisplayImage.png" width="400" height="400" style="position:fixed;     top:0px; left:0px">

</body>
</html>
```

The image is being overwritten constantly while path stays the same.
Is there a way to detect in HTML when the image has been overwritten using javascript (or any other method)?

Comment: Not with straight Javascript.  You would need access to the file system that's holding the file.  So, you'd need a server side script for that.  Then it's just a matter of checking the modified time on it.

Comment: You definitely cannot detect FS changes directly from the client side. You can do A) reload the image every X seconds (with a randomizer at the end of the URL) or B) write a server side script that looks at the file's timestamp and reacts accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

No of course not. If Javascript could do this it could also scan your local documents folder for porn and creditcard numbers.

Comment: This from a guy with 14.7k reputation?  Not that it's incorrect, because it clearly is not.  But it is a rather snarky answer.

Comment: What's snarky about pointing out the most obvious flaw and practical applications of the flaw to make a point? And what does my reputation have to do with it, am I not allowed to answer simple straightforward questions any more now that I'm a 10k+ superdeity?

Comment: And thus why I (nor anyone else, it seems) did not downvote. Because, yes, it certainly does make the point. And one that anyone that asks such questions should be aware of. If only there were some manual or something that explains the security risks that purposefully limit JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

If your image src isn't changing, but the pixels within are changing, you could use canvas [getImageData](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-get-image-data-tutorial/) To save a reference copy of the image, and pull the data again on an interval and test to see if the pixels are different. if any int in the imageData.data array is not the same as your reference copy, then the image has changed.

Comment: This still means continuous polling, instead of 'detecting the file overwrite' as is asked.

Comment: You're going to have to do some sort of change detection if you cannot access the file directly. Perhaps use XHR to make a HEAD request and compare Last-Modified headers. or compare Last-Modified header to a timestamp set on page load, etc.

Answer (score -1):

Ony in case you can control image path. Then you can add some postfix like `DisplayImgage.png?ver=22`

Comment: -1, this does not answer the question, it just points out a way of forcing a cache miss on image change. The question is however on how to detect the image change to begin with.

Comment: image change, sure? "image has been overwritten"

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to detect changes with [Mutation Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events).  Specifically, you can use the DOMAttrModified event to detect when the image's src attribute changes.

Comment: -1, mutation events will obviously not detect a serverside overwrite of the image.